# iOS "unrecognized selector sent to instance" Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, unrecognized-selector

I'm having the popular "unrecognized selector..." problem. The  only issue is that no matter what I do, it never ever is solved. I've gone through every similar question with no avail!

In my code, I'm trying to access a function from "ViewController" through "MyScene". During -viewDidLoad, the transition between "ViewController" and "MyScene" works great, the thing is that it doesn't seem to work in reverse.

From "MyScene", I call a function from "ViewController":

```
if ([_vc respondsToSelector:@selector(eventWasted:)]) {
    [_vc performSelector:@selector(eventWasted:) withObject:self];
}
```

And here is the function in which "MyScene" is calling:

```
- (void)eventWasted:(id)sender {
_flash = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
_flash.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_flash.alpha = .9;
[self.view insertSubview:_flash belowSubview:self.gameOver];

//[self shakeFrame];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.gameOver.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // Display game over
    _flash.alpha = .4;
    self.gameOver.alpha = 1;
    //self.gameOver.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

    self.score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)_myScene.points];
    [Score registerScore:_myScene.points];
    self.bestScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)[Score bestScore]];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    _flash.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}];

}
```

The error presented is

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Calling the function from "MyScene" causes the app to crash. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should add an exception breakpoint to your app, and look at the backtrace

Comment: I know how to add an exception breakpoint, but I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: that's a regular breakpoint, this is an exception breakpoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: UIView does not have a "`showsFPS`" property.  Maybe something in SpriteKit does?  Where is "`showsFPS`" being called or referred to in your code, cause it's not listed in what you've copied & pasted into your question.

Comment: Go to the Breakpoint Navigator in Xcode (Command-7 on Xcode 5), click the + button at the bottom left of the window, and choose **Add Exception Breakpoint…**. It will break on the line where an exception is thrown.

Comment: do you have iAd enabled? For some reason the UIView you send the showsFPS message to is not a SKView

Comment: @LearnCocos2D iAd is not enabled. The `showFPS` line is part of `viewDidLoad` and always works fine during the initial boot of the app. `SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;`

Comment: where else are you using showsFPS? (search your code) Or are you using the same view controller for a different view?

Comment: ViewController is the only place that uses showFPS

Answer (score 0):

I set a boolean value before `viewDidLoad` and told it to only run the first time. I did this by setting the boolean value to `NO` before calling on my `eventWasted:` function. This prevented the `ViewController` and `SKView` from confusing itself with a `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to go to the ViewController's view in the Storyboard. From the identity inspector, change the UIView's class name to `SKView`.
Should resolve it for you.